# Python code won't add to variable

Tags: python

I've written some code for a very basic quiz for a project, but whatever I do the program always outputs what I've set the variable to at the start. It seems to be choosing the right input, and the else statements work, so I can only assume I've done something wrong in the adding to "per" but I can't work out what Here's the code...

```
from random import randint
print(" How like solly are you? Take a test!")
print(" whats your name?")
appendMe = str(input())
input(" press enter to start")
global per
def T(per , a , b , qu):
   per = (per + 0 )
   print(" Input the letter of the answer you choose !")
   print ( qu )
   print ( a )
   print ( b )
   choice = str(input())
   if choice == "A" :
       per = int(per + 10)
   elif choice == "B" :
       per = int(per)
   else:
       print(" Input either A , B , C or D ... Lets try again...")
       Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)



def Q(per , a , b ,c ,d):
       per = (per + 0 )
       cho = int(randint(0,2))
       if cho == 1 :
        print(" Input the letter of the answer you choose !")
        print ( qu )
        print ( a )
        print ( b )
        print ( c )
        print ( d )
        choice = str(input())
        if choice == "A" :
            per = int(per + 5)
        elif choice == "B" :
            per = int(per + 2)
        elif choice == "C" :
             per = int(per)
        elif choice == "D" :
                    per = int(per )
        else:
             print(" Input either A , B , C or D ... Lets try again...")
             Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
    else:
        print(" Input the letter of the answer you choose !")
        print ( qu )
        print ( d )
        print ( c )
        print ( b )
        print ( a )
        choice = str(input())
        if choice == "D" :
            per = int(per + 5)
        elif choice == "C" :
            per = int(per + 2)
        elif choice == "B" :
            per = int(per )
        elif choice == "A" :
            per = int(per)
        else:
            print(" Input either A , B , C or D ... Lets try again...")
            Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)


per = int(50)                
qu = " What is/was/will be your favourite subject at school"
a = " Computer science "
b = " English"
c = " art"
d = " textiles"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " What are your beliefs on body and soul?"
a = " I'm pretty sure the soul dosen't exist..."
b = " Whats a soul?"
c = " I agree with plato , The soul exist and its one with the body"
d = " I agree WTH" ##########
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " Which of these football teams do you support?"
a = " Reading FC"
b = " Arsenal"

c= " I dont supprt any"
d = " Man united"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " Whats your colour?"
a = " pink"
b = " orange "
c = " blue"
d = "black"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " Whats your favourte musica intrstument "
a = " Guitar"
b = " Drums"
c = " piano"
d = " violin"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = "Which of these your favourite sport?"
a = " tennis "
b = " football"
c = " gymastics"
d  = " netball"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = "Which of these is your favourite food?"
a = " Falafel"
b  = "pizza"
c = " pasta"
d = " A burger"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " apple or android?"
a = " android "
b = "apple"
T(per , a , b , qu)
qu = " Which on of these is your favourite TV show"
a = " jundge rinder "
b = " sunday poilitics"
c = " the next step "
d = " strictly come dancing"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " Which type of music is your favorutie "
a = " Pop"
b = " rap"
c = " grime "
d = " classical"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
qu = " Which band is yur favourite?"
a = " One direction"
b = " The vamps"
c = "ACDC"
d = " little mix"
Q(per , a , b ,c ,d)
print("You are " , per , "percent solly!")
appendFile = open(" exampleFile.txt" , "a")
appendFile.write("\n")
appendFile.write(appendMe )
appendFile.write(per)
appendFile.close()
```

Comment: Didn't read the code properly, but is it because of the local variable `per` in both functions? try changing the name.

Comment: `global` should be placed withing the functions, and you should not pass it as a parameter...

Comment: I get an indentation error when I run the code pasted as is.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are mis-using the `global` statement. It should be inside a function, so your functions become

```
def T(a , b , qu):
    global per
    per = (per + 0 )
    etc...

def Q(a , b ,c ,d):
   global per
   per = (per + 0 )
   etc...
```

Edit: You now no longer need to pass `per` as an argument to the function, so you should also remove it from your function calls.

Comment: Why do you need to pass `per` as parameter if you use `global` ?

Comment: I've changed the global to where you suggested , inside the function. But it still won't work, the weird thing is that when I set per to 20 or any other number at the start it still prints it out as 50!

Comment: Try fixing your indentation. Keep it regular, something like four spaces or one tab per indent, and run again.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function, that returns the change in points and don't actually try to change the points.

```
from random import shuffle

def ask(question, answers):
    print("Input the letter of the answer you choose !")
    random.shuffle(answers)
    all_points = {}
    for letter, (answer, points) in zip("ABCDEFG", answers):
        print("{}: {}".format(letter, answer)
        all_points[letter] = points
    while True:
        choice = input()
        if choice in all_points:
            break
        print("Input either A , B , C or D ... Lets try again...")
    return all_points[choice]

per = 50 
per += ask("What is/was/will be your favourite subject at school", [
    (" Computer science ", 5),
    (" English", 2),
    (" art", 0),
    (" textiles", 0)])
per += ask(" What are your beliefs on body and soul?", [
    (" I'm pretty sure the soul dosen't exist...", 5),
    (" Whats a soul?", 2),
    (" I agree with plato , The soul exist and its one with the body", 0),
    (" I agree WTH", 0)])
```